# Word Create Section for Each Row in a Table

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Edit: When I talk about sections I mean whatever the MS Word equivalent to [LaTeX sections](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters) is.

I have a Word Document with a Table.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Title1 | something |
|  | Title2 | foo |
|  | Title3 | bar |

For each row (after the title row), I would like a section (= a heading) to be created *after* the table, with the title of the section being the
contents of column B. If an entry in column B is edited, the title of the section should be updated as well. If an entry is deleted, the section should be deleted.

Is that possible? I'm completely new to VBA and macros.
I don't expect a full solution, more like some ideas on how this problem could be solved with MS Word. Maybe there's some kind of data binding that could be used?

I basically want to do the opposite of creating a table of contents. The workflow of the document will be the following: Some person fills the table with entries, and later another person will have to write a section/paragraph for each row of the table. My idea is to have the section titles (and the styles of those) autogenerate.

Comment: `Section`  is a jargon term in Word. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm A table cannot span sections. Paradoxically, there is a Word feature called `Repeating Section Content Control`. You may want to look into that feature. Neither kind of Section has a title. Could you explain in more detail what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I don't want to create sections within the table, but after the table. I'm not too familiar with Word terminology, but I'd like something like [sections in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters). Not sure what the Word equivalent term would be.

Comment: You would want to insert a new `heading`. That would likely be at a level 1 or level 2 outline level. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the outline-view in word to achieve what you want?